# Nested promises with for loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this nested loop of promises and at then end a for loop that pushes items in the files array.

```
public async content() {
        let files = [];
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
             await this.axios.get(this.currentRequest).then(async biosample => {
                 await this.axios.get(this.currentRequest + biosample.data.item).then(async datasets => {
                     for (let i = 0; i < datasets.data.Items.length; i++) {
                        await this.axios.get(this.currentRequest + datasets.data.Items[i].Id).then(response => {
                            files.push(response.data.Item);
                        }).catch(reason => {
                            reject(reason)
                        });
                    }
                })

            }).catch(function (error) {
                reject(new Error(error.response))
            });
            resolve(files)
        })
    }
```

The calls are made correctly, because if I use `Promise.all([promises here])`, then it works. But I'm trying to learn to chain promises properly.

When I'm debugging with webstorm datasets seems to be defined and have the  necessary properties.

Comment: why are you using .then() with await? async/await is supposed to get rid of then chaining with promises

Comment: @chevybow maybe that's what I'm doing wrong. I'll remove the await/sync

Comment: You should either fully switch to async/await in this snippet or learn about chaining promises. Nesting promises in this way is unneeded in this case.

Comment: @Evert my goal is to learn to nest promises with .then. Probably async/await was messing it up. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Schematically you code must like this

```
content() {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(_ => this.axios.get(this.currentRequest)
        .then(biosample => this.axios.get(this.currentRequest + biosample.data.item))
        .then(datasets => Promise.all(datasets.data.Items.map(item => this.axios.get(this.currentRequest + item.Id))))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the potential of await. Your code can be as simple at this:

```
public async content() {
    let files = [];
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let biosample = await this.axios.get(this.currentRequest)
            let datasets = await this.axios.get(this.currentRequest + biosample.data.item)
            for (let i = 0; i < datasets.data.Items.length; i++) {
                let response = await this.axios.get(this.currentRequest + datasets.data.Items[i].Id)
                files.push(response.data.Item);                 
            }               
            resolve(files)
        } catch(error) {
            reject(new Error(error.response || error))
        };          
    })
}
```